# How to print a response body in actix_web middleware?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'd like to write a very simple middleware using [`actix_web`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.1.0/actix_web/index.html) framework but it's so far beating me on every front.

I have a skeleton like this:

```rust
let result = actix_web::HttpServer::new(move || {
    actix_web::App::new()
        .wrap_fn(move |req, srv| {
            srv.call(req).map(move|res| {
                println!("Got response");
                // let s = res.unwrap().response().body();
                // ???
                res
            })
        })
})
.bind("0.0.0.0:8080")?
.run()
.await;
```

and I can access [`ResponseBody`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.1.0/actix_web/dev/enum.ResponseBody.html) type via `res.unwrap().response().body()` but I don't know what can I do with this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I don't know about responses, and I had misread your question as `RequestBody`. I suspect however that you'll run into the same issue, if the response is a stream. (Issue for the problem of accessing requests: https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/373).

Comment: Probably the answer is to collect the stream into some heap-allocated data structure, and then (somehow) rebuild the stream again into a valid response.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63910673/493729

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how I was able to accomplish this with ***4.0.0-beta.14***:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::str;

use erp_contrib::{actix_http, actix_web, futures, serde_json};

use actix_web::dev::{Service,  ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse, Transform};
use actix_web::{HttpMessage, body, http::StatusCode, error::Error ,HttpResponseBuilder};
use actix_http::{h1::Payload, header};
use actix_web::web::{BytesMut};

use futures::future::{ok, Future, Ready};
use futures::task::{Context, Poll};
use futures::StreamExt;

use crate::response::ErrorResponse;

pub struct UnhandledErrorResponse;

impl<S: 'static> Transform<S, ServiceRequest> for UnhandledErrorResponse
    where
        S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse, Error = Error>,
        S::Future: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse;
    type Error = Error;
    type Transform = UnhandledErrorResponseMiddleware<S>;
    type InitError = ();
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ok(UnhandledErrorResponseMiddleware { service: Rc::new(RefCell::new(service)), })
    }
}

pub struct UnhandledErrorResponseMiddleware<S> {
    service: Rc<RefCell<S>>,
}

impl<S> Service<ServiceRequest> for UnhandledErrorResponseMiddleware<S>
    where
        S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse, Error = Error> + 'static,
        S::Future: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>>>;

    fn poll_ready(&self, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        self.service.poll_ready(cx)
    }

    fn call(&self, mut req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let svc = self.service.clone();

        Box::pin(async move {

            /* EXTRACT THE BODY OF REQUEST */
            let mut request_body = BytesMut::new();
            while let Some(chunk) = req.take_payload().next().await {
                request_body.extend_from_slice(&chunk?);
            }

            let mut orig_payload = Payload::empty();
            orig_payload.unread_data(request_body.freeze());
            req.set_payload(actix_http::Payload::from(orig_payload));

            /* now process the response */
            let res: ServiceResponse = svc.call(req).await?;

            let content_type = match res.headers().get("content-type") {
                None => { "unknown"}
                Some(header) => {
                    match header.to_str() {
                        Ok(value) => {value}
                        Err(_) => { "unknown"}
                    }
                }
            };

            return match res.response().error() {
                None => {
                    Ok(res)
                }
                Some(error) => {
                    if content_type.to_uppercase().contains("APPLICATION/JSON") {
                        Ok(res)
                    } else {

                        let error = error.to_string();
                        let new_request = res.request().clone();

                        /* EXTRACT THE BODY OF RESPONSE */
                        let _body_data =
                            match str::from_utf8(&body::to_bytes(res.into_body()).await?){
                            Ok(str) => {
                                str
                            }
                            Err(_) => {
                                "Unknown"
                            }
                        };

                        let mut errors = HashMap::new();
                        errors.insert("general".to_string(), vec![error]);

                        let new_response = match ErrorResponse::new(&false, errors) {
                            Ok(response) => {
                                HttpResponseBuilder::new(StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST)
                                    .insert_header((header::CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"))
                                    .body(serde_json::to_string(&response).unwrap())
                            }
                            Err(_error) => {
                                HttpResponseBuilder::new(StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST)
                                    .insert_header((header::CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"))
                                    .body("An unknown error occurred.")
                            }
                        };

                        Ok(ServiceResponse::new(
                            new_request,
                            new_response
                        ))
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The extraction of the **Request Body** is straightforward and similar to how Actix example's illustrate. However, with the update to version Beta 14, pulling the bytes directly from `AnyBody` has changed with the introduction of `BoxedBody`. Fortunately, I found a utility function `body::to_bytes` (*`use actix_web::body::to_bytes`*) which does a good job. It's current implementation looks like this:

```
pub async fn to_bytes<B: MessageBody>(body: B) -> Result<Bytes, B::Error> {
    let cap = match body.size() {
        BodySize::None | BodySize::Sized(0) => return Ok(Bytes::new()),
        BodySize::Sized(size) => size as usize,
        // good enough first guess for chunk size
        BodySize::Stream => 32_768,
    };

    let mut buf = BytesMut::with_capacity(cap);

    pin!(body);

    poll_fn(|cx| loop {
        let body = body.as_mut();

        match ready!(body.poll_next(cx)) {
            Some(Ok(bytes)) => buf.extend_from_slice(&*bytes),
            None => return Poll::Ready(Ok(())),
            Some(Err(err)) => return Poll::Ready(Err(err)),
        }
    })
    .await?;

    Ok(buf.freeze())
}
```

which I believe should be fine to extract the body in this way, as the body is extracted from the body stream by `to_bytes()`.

If someone has a better way, let me know, but it was a little bit of pain, and I only had recently determined how to do it in Beta 13 when it switched to Beta 14.

This particular example intercepts errors and rewrites them to JSON format if they're not already json format. This would be the case, as an example, if an error occurs outside of a handler, such as parsing JSON in the handler function itself `_data: web::Json<Request<'a, LoginRequest>>` and not in the handler body. ***Extracting the Request Body and Response Body is not necessary to accomplish the goal, and is just here for illustration.***